# How I can get current user's email from keycloak in jhipster

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster, keycloak

I configured jhipster with ouath 2.0 that use keycloak as the authorization server. But How I can get the current user's email in my app?

Answer (score 1):

When a user logs in via OAuth2, the account [is synchronized to the local user database](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-oauth2/blob/6048b3a2e79d1d7d94174d5dc8ba235df099cb0f/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/service/UserService.java#L157).

In your application exists [`SecurityUtils.java`](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-oauth2/blob/168330750ed7bc6c6fd6edaeb5aeb704a81fcdb1/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/security/SecurityUtils.java#L24) which has a method to get the current user's login.  You can get the login and query for the user/email.

```
String login = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().orElse("anonymoususer");
Optional<User> optionalUser = userService.getUserWithAuthoritiesByLogin(login);
if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
    String email = optionalUser.get().getEmail();
}
```

Comment: with default installation (I use docker image of keycloak and registry) on my local pc, and user admin, it returns null;

Comment: I could not reproduce, once the account is saved in the local database, the information is returned correctly.  I added a line to log the result and see the email, for example `c.m.myapp.web.rest.AccountResource       : admin@localhost`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the AccountService

In your component, you would do something like shown below. You will need to change the values to match your project

```
// Add these imports
import { AccountService } from 'app/core/auth/account.service';
import { Account } from 'app/core/auth/account.model';

@Component({
   selector: 'jhi-pm-your-project-update',
   templateUrl: './pm-your-project-update.component.html',
 })

 export class YourUpdateComponent implements Oninit{
    // Add this varable to store the account information
    account: Account | null = null;

    constructor(
      protected dataUtils: DataUtils,
      protected eventManager: EventManager,
      protected yourService: YourService,
      protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
      protected accountService: AccountService
     ){}
          

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.accountService.identity().subscribe(account => (this.account = account));
 
    }


    save(): void {
      // Here is how to access the email
      yourEntity.lastModifiedBy = this.account?.email;
   
    }
```

}